# How can I use IMAP commands in VB.net to get response from Gmail.com server?

Tags: vb.net, email, imap

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 professional edition and I'm working on a software that part of it is to get the [Inbox] E-mails, but I can not even get a response from the server.

I did these steps:

1. [Made sure that my Gmail.com account is working with IMAP](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799)
2. I'm using 2-step verification method, so I'm using my application password.
3. I'm using this code :

   ```
       Imports System.Net.Sockets
       Imports System.IO
       Imports System.Text        
       Imports System.Net.Security

       Public Class ImapClient1 

       Dim ServerNm As String 
       Dim UsrNm As String
       Dim PassStr As String
       Dim _IntPort As Integer
       Dim ImapClient As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient
       Dim NetworkS_stream As NetworkStream
       Dim m_sslStream As SslStream
       Dim Read_Stream As StreamReader
       Dim StatResp As String

       Function Login(ByVal Sstream As SslStream, ByVal Server_Command As String)
       ImapClient = New TcpClient(ServerNm, _IntPort)
       NetworkS_stream = ImapClient.GetStream 'Read the stream
       Sstream = New SslStream(NetworkS_stream)
       Dim Read_Stream2 = New StreamReader(Sstream)
       Server_Command = Server_Command ' + vbCrLf
       m_buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Server_Command.ToCharArray())
       Sstream.Write(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length)
       Dim Server_Reponse As String
       Server_Reponse = Read_Stream2.ReadLine()
       Return Server_Reponse

   End Function
   ```

When i use this Login function with a [button] like :

```
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        StatResp = Login(m_sslStream, "LOGIN " + UsrNm + " " + PassStr + " ") & vbCrLf
        ListBox1.Items.Add(StatResp)
```

I get nothing in the [ListBox] control.

Comment: I'm using (SslStream) because Gmail.com uses Secure connection SSl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every IMAP command needs to have a "Tag" prefixed in front of it, which is a random alphanumeric string you need to generate.  Typically a login process looks like this:

```
A001 LOGIN user password
A002 SELECT INBOX
A003 ...
...
A010 LOGOUT
```

Comment: I'm sorry but did you even bother yourself to read the question?

Comment: I did, and I see in your code that you're manually concatenating strings together to make commands, without providing tags which are an integral part of commands.  The server will just return 'BAD' responses to your code.  However, your problem is that you can't even connect?  I don't see your definition of servername and port number.  Have you checked whether you can connect at all using a network client like socat?

Comment: The problem was in the server itself, the application is now working.
@Max Thank you.