# How to retrieve the number of E-mail messages from mail server using VB.net and IMAP?

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail, imap

I managed to get a successful reply from the mail server (Gmail.com) using IMAP and vb.net with this code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12126124/1610671)

Now, I want to retrieve the number of E-mail messages from Inbox folder, how to do it?!

Answer (score 1):

After you connect to the server, you'll issue a set of commands like this:

```
A001 LOGIN <username> <password>
A002 SELECT INBOX
```

In response to the SELECT INBOX, the server will respond with a bunch of responses:

```
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 38]
* 13 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
A002 OK Inbox selected.
...
```

The `EXISTS` response is the number of messages in the INBOX.

Comment: I only received this :
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 41.35.202.22 u1if2665077wiz.17
I received almost the same line using (Login) command, but the part after the IP address is changing every time.
What does it mean ?!!!

Comment: That means you've connected, but haven't managed to send it any data.  I think the bit after the IP address is just a random cookie or something, it's not meaningful.

Comment: Well, you need to actually log in.

Comment: You should download a tool like 'socat' and actually connect to the server from the command line and try actually just typing things in.  It's an invaluable debugging tool.  `socat READLINE OPENSSL:server:port,verify=0,crlf`

Comment: You can't use telnet because it doesn't do SSL.

Comment: Thanx Max.
I quit IMAP I will just stick to POP3