# VB.Net - Execute my code when a new email is received

Tags: vb.net, outlook

With VB.Net, I simply would like an event or something to fire when a new email arrives in the Outlook Inbox and I would need that to work **even when Outlook is closed**. When that event fires I will get data from the email received. At work we use the usual Outlook application installed on our Windows computer(not web).

Right now I have code that reads an email even when Outlook is closed but I am missing the above piece, that is I would need my code to work every time a new email is received. I have two ways to do the same thing (see code below) which both work when Outlook is closed, but I need to execute one of the two when a new email arrives and Outlook is closed.
I am new to this so if you could please be simple and provide examples/sample code. Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

**#1 - Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices**

```
        Dim serverURI As New Uri("https://corpmail.....com/ews/exchange.asmx")
        Dim exch As New Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService()
        exch.Url = serverURI
        exch.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        exch.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password",   
                                                                            "domain")

        Dim iv As ItemView = New ItemView(999)
        iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow
        Dim inboxItems As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = Nothing
        inboxItems = exch.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, iv)

        For Each i As Item In inboxItems
            'Console.WriteLine(i.Subject)
            MsgBox("this is" & i.Subject)
            Exit For
        Next
```

**#2**

```
Try
            ' Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            ' to save the email retrieved.
            Dim localInbox As String = String.Format("{0}\inbox",      
                                                   Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())


            ' If the folder does not exist, create it.
            If Not Directory.Exists(localInbox) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox)
            End If


            Dim oServer As New MailServer("corpmail......com",
               "user", "password", ServerProtocol.Pop3)

            oServer.SSLConnection = True
            oServer.Port = 995

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting server ...")


            Dim oClient As New MailClient("TryIt")
            oClient.Connect(oServer)


            ' retrieve unread/new email only
            oClient.GetMailInfosParam.Reset()
            oClient.GetMailInfosParam.GetMailInfosOptions = 
                                                      GetMailInfosOptionType.NewOnly


            Dim infos As MailInfo() = oClient.GetMailInfos()
            Console.WriteLine("Total {0} unread email(s)", infos.Length)


            For i As Integer = infos.Length - 1 To infos.Length - 1
                Dim info As MailInfo = infos(i)
                Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                        info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL)


                ' Retrieve email from IMAP server
                Dim oMail As Mail = oClient.GetMail(info)


                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString())
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}" & vbCr & vbLf, oMail.Subject)


                ' Generate an unique email file name based on date time.
                Dim fileName As String = _generateFileName(i + 1)
                Dim fullPath As String = String.Format("{0}\{1}", localInbox, 
                                                                            fileName)


                ' Save email to local disk
                oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, True)


            'mark unread email as read, next time this email won't be retrieved again
                If Not info.Read Then
                    oClient.MarkAsRead(info, True)
                End If

            Next


            ' Quit and expunge emails marked as deleted from IMAP server.
            oClient.Quit()
            Console.WriteLine("Completed!")

        Catch ep As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: You're going to have to write something to poll the mailbox.  You could either create it as a service, or a regular exe that runs as a scheduled task every X minutes.  The issue with running it as a service is that it isn't associated with any particular user so you'll have a bit more work to do around the issue of users and credentials.  You'll need to be sure you use IMAP when polling.  I did a quick search and it looks like there are some libraries out there that could help, so I think this is do-able.  Be sure you secure the credentials.

Comment: I just looked at your code closer - you're 75% of the way there already! It seems like all you need to do is put your work into a [console application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-visual-basic-console?view=vs-2019) and then [schedule it](https://www.technipages.com/scheduled-task-windows) to run on whatever interval you need.

Comment: I was thinking to just leave the application running but I would need something to catch when a new email is received with Outlook closed. I found a way with an event but that only worked if Outlook was open

Comment: To summarize, with Outlook closed, catch new email, run code #1 above

Comment: For the task scheduler, do I have to use a console application or can it also work on the form load of a VB application?

Comment: Create an EXE and have Task Manager run it.  Your EXE should check Exchange for a new message.  If it finds one, then it runs your code to do things with the messages.  See [this](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/19/programmatically-read-email-from-an-exchange-sever-mailbox/), [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jj12345678910/reading-email-and-attachment-from-microsoft-exchange-server/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871560/using-imap-in-vb-net-to-retrieve-mails-from-ms-exchange-server) for examples of checking Exchange using Exchange WebServices.

Comment: P.S. Task Scheduler can run anything that you could launch from the command line, doesn't matter if it's a console app, winforms, or a batch file.  Also be sure you consider possible run-time and what would happen if an instance was still running when a second one got launched.  You could get a big mess in your scenario, so I'd make it single-instance or use some mechanism to ensure if one's already running, any new instances shut down automatically without doing anything.